# Excel: How to validate hierarchical data for consistency in hierarchy

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a hierarchical data in Excel, like this:

```
Level 1             Level 2         Level 3             GL Name
Current Liabilities Trade Creditors Foreign Creditors   Bob
Current Liabilities Trade Debtors   Foreign Creditors   Mary
Current Assets      Trade Creditors Foreign Creditors   John
```

I need to validate that all occurrences of a level have the same parent hierarchy.
In the above example, the Foreign Creditors in 2nd row has a different Level 2 parent as compared to row 1. The Trade Creditors in row 3 has a different Level 1 parent as compared to row 1.

If the levels are not consistent for a given name, it indicates bad data and I have to flag the same to the finance team. How can I do this validation?

Comment: So is the first occurrence of a level 2 or level 3 description necessarily the reference occurrence? I mean, comparing row 1 and row 3 in the table, which one should be flagged?

Comment: It is ok to flag any one of them or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first occurrence is the reference

Say for row 4, find the reference occurrence (row#)

```
=MATCH(C4, C:C, 0)
```

Check level 2 match

```
=B4=INDEX(B:B, MATCH(C4, C:C, 0))
```

Check level 1 match

```
=A4=INDEX(A:A, MATCH(C4, C:C, 0))
```

Or check both

```
=AND(A4=INDEX(A:A, MATCH(C4, C:C, 0)), B4=INDEX(B:B, MATCH(C4, C:C, 0)))
```

Comment: In terms of a hierarchical tree structure this formula basically verifies that on any level, every child is unique and only has one parent.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that for validity each child value at a given level in the hierarchy is associated with one and only parent value, then lists of the valid parent-child values at each level provide the means of determining not only whether the entire hierarchy is valid but, if it is invalid, where it is invalid.

The general approach is as shown in the simple example below.

[image]

This shows

- hierarchical data in the same the same list format as the original question
- for each parent-child level in the hierarchy the correct parent-child relationship for each possible child value
- a parent validation list identifying whether each child in the hierarcharchical data has the correct parent

If the hierarchical data list has N levels, then N-1 sets of parent-child relationships must be specified. The parent validation list has N-1 columns and the same number of rows as the hierarchical data.

The approach involves checking that each child in the hierarchical data list has the correct parent as specified in the parent-child relationship for that child's level in the hierarchy.

The hard part of this approach is specifying the correct parent-child relationships.  Each set of relationships should represent all the possible child values at a hierarchical level once and once only, so the values in a given child column should be unique. (There are various ways in Excel of determining the unique values in a list, including the `UNIQUE` function in the latest versions of Excel. If this function is not available, the Data menu provides a way of removing duplicates and this can be performed on a **copy of** the columns of the hierarchical data.)

In the worksheet shown, conditional formatting has been used to highlight cells in the hierarchical data which show as an incorrect parent-child pair. Two formatting rules were used one for cell `A3`and the second for cell `B3`. In both rules the formula `NOT(J3)` was used. The format painter was used to copy the format of `A3` to range `A3:B11` and `B3` to `B3:C11`.

In reviewing any errors flagged it must be born in mind that it could be the child or parent of the highlighted parent-child pair that is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks. This can be a good generalized solution for n levels when we have a predefined set of valid values. But I do not have a fixed set of valid values for each parent-child for a particular level.

Comment: You at least need to know the correct parent for all the different child values that exist in your data at a given level. The "fixed set of valid values" can be specific to each hierarchical data set. Without this information you are left with something like Mobus' assumption that the first occurrence of a parent-child pair in the hierarchical data is always correct.  As my worksheet example shows, this is not necessarily true: the pair CB-CCB occurs only once in the data but is incorrect. To check data, you need to know the criteria you are checking against. No short cuts, unfortunately.

Comment: The objective is to find inconsistent hierarchical data. What is correct or not correct will be decided manually by the business users.